# Converting WinPE/ISO to WIM for WDS

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, pxe, wds

Is there a way to convert boot images to WIM so that they work in Windows Deployment Services?

I have a file that was created PartAssist_WinPE.iso but contains no .wim file.

Does WDS only support .wim or windows os? Will I need another PXE service to support my other ISOs?

Answer (score 3):

You use imagex.exe to capture the file system.  Mount the ISO as a drive letter, and then use imagex to capture that to a wim file.

Comment: `imagex.exe /capture`

Answer (score -1):

This is also possible using the command line tools in WAIK (7, at least), for the record.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: In the "Walkthrough: Create a Bootable Windows PE RAM Disk on CD-ROM" section of the WAIK instructions, it shows after detailing how to modify a wim image, to commit it to an iso file using the oscdimg command line tool which is installed with the Deployment Command Line tools.

With a wim file in the proper path and/or naming convention, the command would be something like this:

"oscdimg -n -bC:\winpe_x86\etfsboot.com C:\winpe_x86\ISO  C:\winpe_x86\winpe_x86.iso"